# Some vs a lot can they be interchangeable?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, questions

According to numerous dictionaries, some can also emphasize that a quantity/amount is quite large.

Therefore, could I say "There is SOME juice in the glass" with the same meaning as " a lot of"?

If "some time" with the meaning "a lot of time" works etc, why wouldn't "some juice" work as well?

My teacher contradicted me when I said this today...

Here are some of the senses of *some*:

> **some** DETERMINER
>
> - 1 **An unspecified amount or number of**.
>
> ‘I made some money running errands’
>
> - 2 Used to refer to someone or something that is unknown or unspecified.
>
> ‘I was talking to some journalist the other day’
>
> - 3 (used with a number) approximately.
>
> ‘some thirty different languages are spoken’
>
> - 4 **A considerable amount or number of**.
>
> ‘he went to some trouble’...
>
> 'Later in this chapter we shall consider in some detail two striking examples.’
>
> ‘She has been directing films for some years now.’ [AHD]

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/some)]

Comment: Hello, Martin. 'According to numerous dictionaries, some can also emphasize that a quantity/amount is quite large.' Please give a couple of examples of this, preferably with example sentences from the dictionaries you mention here.

Comment: _Some_ of the Pacific Ocean can usually be found in the Polynesian region, I've heard say. :) That is a considerable or large amount of water.

Answer (score 2):

[[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/some)] lists the 'quite a lot of' (as opposed to 'more than zero') sense of the polysemic determiner **some**:

> *some* determiner (LARGE AMOUNT)
>
> a large amount or number of something:
>
> - *It'll be some time before we meet again.*
> - *It was some years later when they next met.*
> - *We discussed the problem at some length.*
> - *It took some effort to get the thing upstairs.*
> - *In the end she agreed but she took some persuading.*
> - *Will you phone me back - it's a matter of some importance.*
> - *Green's new world record will take some beating.*

In each of these cases, 'some' may be substituted by 'quite some' and/or 'quite a lot of' and/or 'quite a few'. Note that this sense of 'some' may be used with both count and non-count nouns.

Note also the grading into the corresponding [determiner+adjective] usage:

- That was some party!  (= 'That was *a remarkable* party'; see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/some)) This usage can be seen neither as purely quantitive ('a bit of / a lot of / a small / a large') nor purely adjectival (*'That was remarkable party').

The specific string [determiner [some] + noun/ing-form [N]] are not what force the 'large/largish amount' sense, at least not always:

- I have some time now; let's go for a walk.
- Some years are wetter than others.

However, the 'more than zero' and the 'certain examples' senses are not readily available with say 'persuading', 'importance' ... (one sees these are abstract ideas, but then so is 'time'). Of course, one can contrive exceptions ('Some effort will always be required' / 'These clothes lines are all too short. We'll find some length that will fit.')

- 'There is some juice in the glass' would almost always default to the 'more than zero' sense. The 'large amount' sense would be overblown unless one were with say Hagrid.
- 'There is some water in that reservoir' is, however, ambiguous without context; heavily stressing 'some' (perhaps bolding rather than using italics in print ... and probably an exclamation mark at the end of the sentence) forces the 'an appreciable amount' sense. A reservoir can hold a considerable (heading towards 'vast' here) amount, so this is not an incongruous usage.  But the 'It's not empty' sense is also readily available.

Yes, there's ambiguity here. As usual, context will disambiguate in practice.